# Need help creating an array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two Sheets

A "MEMBER" Sheet - 600 rows.

A "MODERATOR" Sheet - 13 rows (this is a subset of the "MEMBER" sheet)

Both sheets share a "Member Key" column - all unique values to identify the members.

I want to create a function that does the following

"...For every row in the MEMBER sheet..."

"...Compare the Member Key column in the MODERATOR sheet."

"If the Member Key column matches..."

"...pull values from that specific row in the MEMBER sheet..."

"and copy them into the MODERATOR sheet row with the matching KEY column"

The code is supposed to update the Moderator record with information from its correspondence Member record

the code I wrote for it is below.

The code runs, but the values don't update. I assume it's related to the for loop I applied. I'm hoping to resolve this issue by using object functions in the arrays, but I've had diffiuclty applying them in my code.

Grateful for any feedback on my question or code in general

```
function Moderator_Update() {


  var Metrics = SpreadsheetApp.openById("10Wl1B4AtdLHJXBbLbMQbSdtRyAb61biCWYpOQEEywIY");  // METRICS spreadsheet
  var Data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // DATA spreadsheet

  var ModsDataSheet = Data.getSheetByName("The Moderator_Numbers");  // DATA "Member" sheet
  var ModsAllValues = ModsDataSheet.getRange(2, 1, ModsDataSheet.getLastRow()-1,ModsDataSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues(); //All values in DATA "Members" sheet

  var MembersDataSheet = Data.getSheetByName("The Member_Numbers") // DATA "Moderator" sheet
  var MembersAllValues = MembersDataSheet.getRange(2, 1, MembersDataSheet.getLastRow()-1,MembersDataSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  for(var MO = ModsAllValues.length-1;MO>=0;MO--) // for each row in the "Moderator" sheet...
  {

    for(var M = MembersAllValues.length-1;M>=0;M--) // for each row in the "Member" sheet...
    { 

        if (MembersAllValues[M][17] == ModsAllValues[MO][27])  // If Member KEY matches Moderator Key.
        { 

          // delcare the following variables with values from the Member Sheet
          var Mod_MemberName = MembersAllValues[M][0];
          var Mod_MemberWebPage = MembersAllValues[M][2];
          var Mod_MemberTag = MembersAllValues[M][4];
          var Mod_MemberFirstName = MembersAllValues[M][5];
          var Mod_MemberLastName = MembersAllValues[M][6];
          var Mod_MemberEmail = MembersAllValues[M][7];


          // assign those values to the following cells in the Moderator Sheet
          ModsAllValues[MO][0] = Mod_MemberName;
          ModsAllValues[MO][2] = Mod_MemberWebPage;
          ModsAllValues[MO][5] = Mod_MemberTag;
          ModsAllValues[MO][6] = Mod_MemberFirstName;
          ModsAllValues[MO][7] = Mod_MemberLastName;
          ModsAllValues[MO][8] = Mod_MemberEmail;

       }
    } 
  }

   var ModDestinationRange = ModsDataSheet.getRange(2, 1, ModsAllValues.length, ModsAllValues[0].length); 

      ModDestinationRange.setValues(ModsAllValues);
}
```

[Moderator Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGJsR.png)
[Member Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3vdk.png)

Comment: Is ModsAllValues getting the correct values? Are you updating the spreadsheet using setValue() for example ? Here you are only modifyng the variables but not updating the sheet.

Comment: @m.rp I did have code in there to set the values (see new code). I omitted it from my original post because it including it didn't have any effect. I don't think the problem is updating the sheet.

Comment: Could you provide a sample sheet so we can take a look at if what you are doing makes sense? 
Maybe you should try to update in each row because right now you are overwriting the ModsDataSheet.

Comment: sure @Raserhin i added the images that the top. Simply put. All the names in the Moderator sheet also show up in the Member sheet. I highlighted an example. (I'm not a super cool dude yet, so the images are not embedded)  What a want is a function that says? "If a member name is also in the moderator sheet, update the information so that other Moderator row matches the member row."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

It's not fastest possible solution but this way you don't have to worry about the effects of overwriting values that are not a part of the update.

```
function Moderator_Update() {
  var Data=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mdsh=Data.getSheetByName("The Moderator_Numbers");
  var mdvA=mdsh.getRange(2,1,mdsh.getLastRow()-1,mdsh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var mrsh=Data.getSheetByName("The Member_Numbers");
  var mrvA=mrsh.getRange(2,1,mrsh.getLastRow()-1,mrsh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var mdkeyA=mdsh.getRange(2,28,mdsh.getLastRow()-1,mdsh.getLastColumn()).getValues().map(function(r){return r[0];});
  for(var j=0;j<mrvA.length;j++) { 
    var i=mdkeyA.indexOf(mrvA[j][17]);
    if(i>-1){ 
      mdsh.getRange(i+2,1).setValue(mrvA[j][0]);
      mdsh.getRange(i+2,3).setValue(mrvA[j][2]);
      mdsh.getRange(i+2,6).setValue(mrvA[j][4]);
      mdsh.getRange(i+2,7).setValue(mrvA[j][5]);
      mdsh.getRange(i+2,8).setValue(mrvA[j][6]);
      mdsh.getRange(i+2,9).setValue(mrvA[j][7]);
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Is this solution working for you? Could you accept it if that's the case?

Comment: apologies. I decided to go in a different direction, but I'll accept this answer

Comment: Thanks have a great day